# Regex php find a character within html tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm stuck on a stubborn problem I can't seem to solve.

I'm trying to find a specific character only when it is inside an html tag (not between).

To test this I have 2 test strings:

1. a string with NO HTML. this is sentence 2.
2. a string with **some** HTML. `this is <a href="www.somesite.com">sentence</a>`

I'd like to find all the period characters within < > html tags so the match should be 2 periods within www.somesite.com, I cannot get the match correctly. Can someone please take a look at my regex and see what I am missing?

```
(<[^>]*>?(\.))>?
```

Comment: Use a dom parser and inspect element attributes, don't parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: this doesn't look like a properly formatted regex pattern, what function are you using?

Comment: Even if you match a period within an html tag, what information can you possibly get from that? Maybe its more than a period. Given that, you have to do this in 2 steps. First, capture the contents of the tag (that contain what needs to be found) then parse the contents separately.

Comment: Try `<([^>]*\.[^>]*)>`, then split $1 on `.`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$re = "/>[^<]*<(*SKIP)(*F)|searchText/mi";   //before | part avoid tag inner text and after | part search only tag inside text.
$str = "<div><a href=\"www.searchText.com\">This is <a href=\"www.searchText.com\">sentence</a> tI want to test.</a></div>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU2mX1/2)

Comment: Probably the closest you'll get with a regex. Too bad my own HTML would break that because I don't escape `>` as `&gt;` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given the string "`This is <a href="www.somesite.com">sentence</a> I want to test.`" the regex:

```
\.(?=\w)
```

will match the periods in the URL but not at the end of the sentence. ***Note*** *that the regex is not URL specific, it just finds a period followed immediately by a word character using a positive lookahead.*

Having said that you should really be parsing HTML with something like [PHPDomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Your regular expression `\.(?=\w)` will match things regardless of if they're in a HTML tag or not.  For example: `I have $5.00 in my wallet` will be matched even though it has no HTML.